# rounding up php numbers with my addition

Tags: php, rounding

This is the php I have written which is slightly mixed with some wordpress functions.

However, I want all the values to be rounded to one decimal place, but I cannot work out how to do it - the php below is pretty basic - but I cannot work out the next step for the decimals.

```
<?php
$one_decimal_place = number_format(2.10, 1);
// AVERAGE DRINK COSTS 
$li2 = get_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night');
$li3 = ($li2 * 28) * 2.1;
$li4 = $li3 * 3;

// HOUSING COSTS 
$li22 = (get_field('average_housing_costs_per_week') * 4 );
$li33 = $li22 * 12;
$li44 = $li33 * 3;

// SHOPPING COSTS 
$li222 = (get_field('average_shopping_trip_price') * 2.25 );
$li333 = $li222 * 12;
$li444 = $li333 * 3;

// TUITION FEES 
$tuitionClass = (get_field('tuition_fees') /28 );
$tuitionTotal = (get_field('tuition_fees') * 3 );

// PHP TCE 
$totalcost2 = $li444 + $tuitionTotal;
$totalcost3 = $li4 + $li44;
$totalcost = $totalcost2 + $totalcost3; 
?>
```

Comment: for clarification: do you want to round the number regular, as stated in the text (0.245 -> 0.2) or do you always want to round up, as stated in the title (0.245 -> 0.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tried  function [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)??

```
$test = 15.321321321;
echo round($test,1);
```

Result: 15.3;

And if you wan't round UP like my friend said should try to use this:

```
$test = 15.321321321;
echo round($test,1,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Resulto: 15.4

Comment: this will not always round "up" as asked in the question.

Comment: I don't know where you see the question to round "up"..... round is round if you force round up or down isn't round. if next decimal place > 5 round up else round down. It's the expect behavior

Comment: The title of the question is `rounding up php numbers`.

Comment: Brilliant! 

Guerra - cannot thank you enough! Simple placement of the round is where I was getting confused, thank you all that helped.